# Opening multiple files as layers in a single image in Elements?

Tags: layers, images, adobe-photoshop-elements

In Elements (I'm using version 9 for Mac), is there a single operation that will let me open a bunch of files as one image, with each file as a layer in that image?

If I were using GIMP, for example, I'd choose "open as layers", and that would add multiple files as layers on the top of my current image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Photoshop is easy, making an Action (sort of macro) and then applying it in file menu/automate/batch.  In Elements, you cannot make actions, you can use actions which are premade and given free or sold, done by full Photoshop users.

There is an super cheap (12$) addon that you can get, which adds batch funcionalities to Elements 9. You can there use it to open multiple files and even do operations to it, etc. I haven't checked if one of the many scripts of the pack does actually that, but you could look there:

http://elementsplus.net/v3/en/batch.htm

The main page is:

http://simplephotoshop.com/elementsplus/

Comment: Thank you! It's good to know that I wasn't missing something obvious. I'll take a look at Elements+ (or just head back to the Gimp...)